# Displaying unique attributes of table and the total value in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have one table with columns stamp_type and amount as follows

```
                          stamp_type                          | amount
--------------------------------------------------------------+--------
 GENERAL STAMP                                                |  11000
 GENERAL STAMP                                                |  25000
 COURT FEE STAMP                                              |   9800
 SPECIAL ADHESIVE                                             | 721000
 GENERAL STAMP                                                | 125000
 COURT FEE STAMP                                              |  21000
```

Now I want to display as follows:

```
    stamp_type                                                    | amount
    GENERAL STAMP                                                   161000
    COURT FEE STAMP                                                 30800
    SPECIAL ADHESIVE                                                721000

TOTAL:912800
```

I am unable to display the unique values. can any one give suggest me the query. I tried to use Distinct but dint work.

Comment: You want `GROUP BY` and the aggregate function `sum`. To add a total at the end is frustratingly complicated with SQL; you need to use a `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code::

```
 select stamp_type, sum(amount) amount
    from tbl
    group by stamp_type
 union
 select 'Total:' stamp_type,sum(amount) amount
 from tbl;
```

Comment: Yup, this also works with little bit changes..Use of union dint click to me..Nevertheless thanks..

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from 
(
select  0 as srt, stamp_type, sum(amount) as SumAmount from t group by stamp_type
union 
select 1 as srt, 'Total' as stamp_type, sum(amount) as SumAmount from t 
) b order by srt
```

Comment: Good point; I failed to ensure reliable sorting of the total at the end of the result set in my answer.

Comment: This too worked.. I would probably use separate query for grand total. thanks!!